# how do I install LibreOffice to my computer?

Tags: installation, download, libreoffice

I'm new to computers and I don't know how to download or install programs to my computer.

I have not tried anything. I do not want to download or install a file that is not the correct program and break my computer or the internet.

Comment: Just read [what **The Document Foundation** writes](https://www.libreoffice.org/get-help/install-howto/) on this topic - you will succeed